# The while..do loops in C

Tags: c

I've just studied C programming recently. In fact, I'm a beginner in programming. Currently, I'm reading the book called: C programming, Absolute beginner's guide.
I don't quite understand this, they use the do...while loop:

```
if (choice == 'n')
    {
        choice = 'N';
    }
} while (choice != 'N');
```

This is used in case user types 'n' instead of N. But I retyped like this:

```
while ((choice != 'N')||(choice!='n'));
```

The while loop still continues

Sorry guys, dude to tha lack of time (I nearly missed my school buss)
Here is the complete original code from the book:

```
float num1, num2, result;
char choice;
do {
    printf("Enter your first number to multiply: ");
    scanf(" %f", &num1);
    printf("Enter your second number to multiply: ");
    scanf(" %f", &num2);
    result = num1 * num2;
    printf("%.2f times %.2f equals %.2f\n\n",
        num1, num2, result);
    printf("Do you want to enter another pair of numbers ");
    printf("to multiply (Y/N): ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    // If the user enters a lowercase n, this if statement will
    // convert it to an N
    if (choice == 'n')
    {
        choice = 'N';
    }
} while (choice != 'N');
return 0;
```

Comment: Where is the `do?`?

Comment: your condition is always true

Comment: There's no `do` in either snippet you posted. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: unable to understand your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're boolean logic is incorrect, what you are looking for is...

```
while ((choice != 'N')&&(choice!='n'));
```

In the case of using OR if either case is true it continues and as such it always will

| Choice |  choice!='N' | choice !='n' | OR | AND |
| X | true | true | true | true |
| n | true | false | true | false |
| N | false | true | true | false |